# Filter condition based on user input Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions, scala-collections

I have to apply the filter condition based on the user Inputs. Assume below condition and "mod" is the user filter condition string input.

```
df.filter(df("rollnumber").mod(2))
```

How can I write a function that takes parameters as filtercolumnname,filtercondition,filtervalue and apply it on data frame ?

Expectation:

```
def applyfiltering(filtercolumnname: String,filtercondition : String,filtervalue : String) ={

df.filter(df("rollnumber").mod(2))

}

applyfiltering("rollnumber","mod","2")
```

Thanks in Advance

I just tried like this :

```
df.filter(df("rollnumber").cast("===")(2)).toDF
df.filter(df("rollnumber").cast("mod")(2)).toDF
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like if there is known set of what user can ask to do:

```
val cond1 = df1("rollnumber").mod(lit(2))
val cond2 = df1("rollnumber") === lit(2)

def applyFiltering(column: Column): Unit = {
  df1.filter(column)
}

applyFiltering(cond2).show
```

Another approach is :

```
def applyFiltering(colName: String, filtercondition: String, filtervalue: Any): DataFrame = {
  val dfCol = df1(colName)
  val fltValue = lit(filtervalue)
  val flt: Column =
    if (filtercondition == "===")  dfCol === fltValue 
    else if (filtercondition == "mod") dfCol.mod(fltValue)
    else throw new UnsupportedOperationException()

  df1.filter(flt)
}

applyFiltering("rollnumber", "===", 2)
```